# How can i use a formula in Excel to match values from one column and return values from another

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I have current employees names in column A  and all current and past employees  names column AD and ID numbers in column AC. I want to find a name in column A is in column AD and assign the ID number. Ether the ID number in column G

Comment: Don't assume part of the answer in the question (or title). You can't do this with VLOOKUP because AD and AC are the wrong way round (VLOOKUP can only lookup in first column and return from a column to the right of that). 
Instead, make the question more general and then you might get an answer that will work, using MATCH and INDEX for example.

Answer (score 1):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(AC:AC,MATCH(A2,AD:AD,0)),"")`

Comment: Could you please explain how this works.  That would improve the quality of the answer.